# Google App Engine database viewer/browser?

Tags: database, google-app-engine

Does Google App Engine offer any kind of database browser/viewer tool which can show **CURRENT** data? 1-day late database view was offered, however, it's not enough.

Comment: Where do you see a 1-day-late database view?

Comment: @Wooble, @Adam A few months ago... as I remember GAE didn't offered immediate data viewer. However it looks not anymore :)

Comment: GAE has never offered to let you view yesterday's data. The datastore viewer has always been realtime since it was introduced.

Comment: Datastore statistics (storage space by kind and type) are not immediate, and make take 24 hours to update. Maybe that is what @Eonil was thinking of. Either that, or they dreamt it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

appengine.google.com has its own datastore viewer. where you can login and view the complete datastore for all your applications. In the development server, appengine SDK emulates the same. You can access it like http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin

Answer (score 11):

Datastore on the appengine is accessible at, 
https://console.developers.google.com/datastore/entities/query?project=yourappid
(replace yourappid appropriately)

This will be the current data.

Answer (score 5):

I think that datastore viewer in development server can be accessed through http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GoogleAppEngineLauncher, you can see Admin Port and the Port. Go to the Admin Port to access the datastore.