# JDO basics: List or array won't retrieve or return with GWT RPC

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, gwt-rpc

I've been using Objectify up till now, but now I have to deal with some code using JDO.
I'm having problems with basic stuff that is easy with Objectify, specifically: if an object
has either a List or an array as a member, I can't get that to persist.

I have a class FileInfoBatch (code indents lost here, don't know why)
containing a List of FileInfo:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class FileInfoBatch implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;        
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

@Persistent
private List<FileInfo> fileInfoList;    

@Persistent    
private String savedByUserEmail;

public FileInfoBatch(){         
    fileInfoList=new ArrayList<FileInfo>();     
}
```

Then I send a FileInfoBatch (called fib) containing just 1 FileInfo in the List, to my RPC impl class & persist it, then query for it straight away for a test (in debugger)

```
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    pm.makePersistent(fib);
    Query query = pm.newQuery(FileInfoBatch.class, "savedByUserEmail == '"+ userEmail + "'");
    List<FileInfoBatch> savedList = (List<FileInfoBatch>) query.execute();
    FileInfoBatch persisted=savedList.get(0);
```

The persisted FileInfoBatch comes back with an empty FileInfo list.
If I use a single Fileinfo member, this persists ok.

I find no such basic problem reported on this site & I've looked at the docs:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses

Does such a simple storage task require huge complexity? If so I will go back
to using Objectify.

Comment: Judging by the comments below, everything is persisted and retrieved ok with Lists, which matches my experience; your only problem is in GWT and RPC and not using the current release. I'd suggest you update your question with that so others coming on here see the real situation

Comment: Everything in my system is up to date. Other people are having same problem as me. See link below. They are having to copy List data on retrieval because the JDO enhanced classes won't return via RPC. I am using Objectify now again, as it is not problematic, for basic stuff like saving an object with a list.

Comment: Well no it isn't; you are doing three things ... persist (which works), retrieve (which works), and RCP. The latter is the part where you have a problem. Your question (still) says something doesn't persist, which is wrong. I'd suggest you focus on individual problems, like I get these objects in my Java code, and then perform this RCP operation. That's what Stackoverflow is for, specific things. If you want to use Objectify then just do it without the bitching, lifes too short. If you want help getting JDO working then express things in simple questions about a specific step

Comment: @Neil OK I have now changed the question. I didn't realize the stuff was persisting as I didn't know about Datastore viewer. But it is not retrieving (when I look at the server in debugger), & RPC throws an exception related to a class from a previous junk version of Datanucleus.

Comment: @Neil I am bitching & harping on about Objectify to warn others to take that route rather than wasting time with JDO in GWT. If you want basic Datastore functionality, use Objectify: avoids days wasted with tedious versioning issues

Comment: The post says "doesn't persist". Yes I looked at the linked blog and indeed there were some people from 2010 who had problems. There are also people from 2011-2012 who quite clearly say that if you detach then they have no problem passing Lists down the wire. So no, people won't be wasting time using JDO. End of the FUD

Answer (score 0):

Define "doesn't persist"? Have you looked at the [log](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/logging.html) (which tells you what is included in a PUT of an Entity) or the [DB viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335721/google-app-engine-database-viewer-browser) for what is persisted? Is "FileInfo" marked as PersistenceCapable?

More than likely it is persisted, but you haven't paid attention to defining what is fetched (in JDO you get FULL control over what is in the retrieved object). Suggest that you read http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/object_lifecycle.html
and http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/fetchgroup.html

Are you using a recent version of "datanucleus-appengine" ? (i.e **v2.0 or later**); the old versions aren't worth the effort.

PS, you don't need @Persistent on field types such as String, Key - makes things look much cleaner.

FWIW : JDO provides as simple a persistence choice as there is, as transparent as other options out there, and with semantics defined by a spec in way more detail than other options.

Comment: It has not persisted means that when I try to use the 1 & only entry in the List, once it goes into datastore, it is gone, not retrievable in the simple form in which it was stored. I am using GWT 2.5 & App Engine 1.7. I shouldn't have to install anything else for JDO should I?

Comment: To be more precise, the retrieved List is EMPTY. The List entry has gone, not persisted.  Do I really have to read lots on object life cycles? I just want to save an object containing an array, or a List

Comment: You don't say what version of "datanucleus-appengine" you're using, as already said you need v2.0+ (its in your apps jars somewhere). As also asked, you have a log that tells you what PUTs are performed (and a datastore viewer that tells you what is present in the datastore); it is recommended to look at it. All remaining points rely on the answers to those.

Comment: If you want to refer to standard tests there are plenty in http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/jdo/ with samples under http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/#datanucleus%2Ftest%2Fjdo

Comment: What & where is the log which tells you what is included in a PUT of an Entity? What is the DB viewer? Why should I need to do all this for such a basic task? I just want to save an array or a List, & have it come back as it was saved. Obviously if I want subtlties then I have have to dig deeper, but I don't want anything subtle, just want it to save a simple List or array, just save it, as member of an object.

Comment: Tests are not what I need, just persistance. The FileInfo object persists ok as a single object member, but not as a List or array. Of course "FileInfo" is marked as PersistenceCapable.Are you saying google could be distributing a version of DN that fails in this basic functionality?

Comment: I put links to GAE DB viewer, and log in the answer. I simply provided some tips on how you can debug your problem, since without basic information like what version of the software you're using nobody can help you. Checking if something is persisted is the most basic step. Tests show you how to do persistence and are good reference.

Comment: I converted datanucleus to V2.

Re datastore viewer at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Chrome says can't connect

Comment: Re log: I looked at your link, so: for JDK1.4 or later java.util.logging will be used. OK but where is the  log file ?
Can you tell me if my annotations are wrong? I use type Key for parent object and fo child (which has the List). Correct?

Comment: JDK logging ? likely it will dump into the appengine console unless you configure a logging.properties (see java.util.logging docs). Your classes look fine (though I can't see the child class). Here's a simple one like yours for reference (parent, then child) http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/test/jdo/Issue90Parent.java http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/test/jdo/Issue90Child.java

Comment: the simple classes are same as mine except mine both have implements Serializable, for GWT RPC.

Comment: So the final step is to look at the persistence code for that GAE test at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/jdo/Issue90Test.java  It persists a Parent, then adds two Child objects to the List. It then checks the results with pm.getObjectById inside a transaction. Do that with yours, and also using a query inside a transaction, and then finally the query outside the transaction. If it doesn't load the list immediately you can add "query.getFetchPlan().setGroup("all") which will load all fields (JDO fetch group feature).

Comment: Its a GWT/JDO issue I think: rpc is failing, but ONLY if the server uses PersistenceManager (otherwise the classes serialize ok in debugger)
Error  msg: 
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: 
Type 'org.datanucleus.sco.backed.ArrayList' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded.

Comment: You're obviously using "datanucleus-appengine" v1.x then (which uses datanucleus-core v1.1.x) since that referred to class is not present in later releases. So I'd recommend upgrading to the current release of "datanucleus-appengine" (present in the current GAE SDK)

Comment: As Iunderstand it, both parent & child classes are enhanced in PersistenceManager. For a child with single object member the list of parents can't be returned to client, so I have been returning a copy. This works ok: the enhancements are removed in both parents & childs, but if the child is in a list, the list just gets emptied

Comment: No I swithed to V2 in Properties>Google>App Engine>Datnucleus version & that's the error I get

Comment: btw, I tried just using an array instead of a list, and error was: FK Arrays not supported

Comment: someone said use @PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")(on child class?). Also, GWT module file should include fully-qualified class name in the rpc.enhancedClasses configuration property ?? but it hasn't required this for single child member?

Comment: yes, use "detachable" (on both classes) if you want to detach objects from persistence (to pass them to a different layer).

Comment: There are 2 classes but console says DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.0.m2) : Enhancement of classes
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 1 classes.

Comment: http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/ seems to work now, it says the child in the list is saving, but I can't access it, I can't even return from the rpc

Comment: both classes have serialVersionUID = 1L; Nothing wrong there I assume

Comment: Can you confirm there is no solution or are you looking at it still? If there's no solution I will return to Objectify, where I had no problems

Comment: Solution? As already said, I can persist and retrieve objects with Lists and access them fine (see that GAE test). Plenty of people use GWT (v2+) with JDO with detached objects. As also previously said that class in your RPC method is not present in datanucleus-appengine v2.x (and the DataNucleus related jars) so you still have old jars present

Comment: FYI support for arrays was added with this issue http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=263&can=1&q=array&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20FoundIn%20TargetRelease%20Owner%20Summary in version 2.0.1, hence if you get some exception then you're not using that version at runtime

Comment: My datanucleus jars are all numbered starting 2 & 3 eg /war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.0-final.jar. Where else might the offending jars be located? I cleaned project & rebuilt.

Comment: Vaguely remember someone else trying the "upgrade" route and having some problem until he found the right place to delete from; think I pointed them at this doc that Google wrote (give it a try and see if it shows the old location)  http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/UpgradingToVersionTwo    Either that or just get the latest GAE SDK (1.7.3) which includes v2.x by default.

Comment: I just got GAE SDK 1.7.3. added it as default, set my project to the same. Previously GAE 1.7.2 was being used from the eclipse plugin bundle. Type 'org.datanucleus.sco.backed.ArrayList' is still reported. Is this the class that is outdated? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: should I delete appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1 from the eclipse bundle?

Comment: That class doesn't exist (was only present in DataNucleus v1.x). Using "jar" on the datanucleus-core.jar would confirm that.

Comment: OK I believe you, but where is the offending jar? I have deleted the old GAE SDK in the eclipse bundle, same error. Should I delete files from the new GAE SDK? That's the only place they can be hiding isn't it? Which files should I delete?

Comment: Mr DataNucleus you say lots of people have no problem. Maybe they got bored & tried something else. Why don't you point me to a sample that does List or array in GWT RPC? Why don't you know why your old jars get used when they shouldn't be? Its a bit limp

Comment: Mr "timmacp", I've spent quite a lot of time answering your questions on here. I haven't as yet received the words "thanks". Then to get some statements of "limp" really says it all. Do I know where you put the jars ? Nope. I personally don't use GWT but have had feedback (on Stackoverflow, and other sites) that all works with the current plugin and GWT on their apps; do a Google search for "GAE GWT JDO" or similar. What do I do ? I simply put some of my spare time into developing Googles plugin after they failed to provide a worthwhile release with version 1; is that worthy of dissing?

Comment: @ DataNucleus Lots of people are still having this problem in 2012, see http://blog.cloudglow.com/2010/04/google-app-engine-arraylist-jdo-object.html  They're having to keep a separate List for datastore which can't be serialized

Comment: Mr DataNucleus, I assumed from your ID you represent DataNucleus, thus I apologize & thanks for your efforts, but I feel the system is a complete load of xxxx. I put the jars in the same folder as all other jars, and the old ones are not there, or anywhere

Comment: O dear you have given me a black mark. Look if you can't solve a problem in your area then just say so.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything,. There's nothing I can do when you're not using v2 of the GAE JDO plugin (the only thing I contribute to in your software chain, and all of your replies demonstrate that it is not being used). How you upgrade the AppEngine SDK is the issue, suggest you go to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-appengine and ask for help there.