# Persistent list in JDO (Google App Engine)

Tags: java, database, list, jdo, persistent

I`m developing the server side for a mobile app with Google App Engine and JDO in Java, and I have some problems saving objects list in the database.

I have a one-to-many relationship between conversation and messages (I`m trying to do a chat-like application). A conversation has a list of messages and a message belongs to a conversation.
When I do makePersistent of a conversation, if I get the same conversation with the ID, all is fine and the list is returned with the messages. But if I close that instance of the PersistenceManager and I try to get the conversation in another method, the conversation is all fine (the attributes like hour, idUser, etc), except for the list of messages which is null. No matter what changes I do, that list is always null.

Here is my code:

**Conversation.java:**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)  
public class Conversation 
{
    @PrimaryKey  
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)  
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private Long idUser;

    @Persistent(mappedBy = "conversation")
    private LinkedList<Message> messages;

    public Conversation(Long idUser) 
    {
        this.idUser = idUser;

        messages = new LinkedList<Message>();       
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public LinkedList<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

**Message.java:**

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)  
public class Message 
{
    @PrimaryKey  
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)  
    private Key id;

    @Persistent
    private Conversation conversation;

    @Persistent
    private String text;

    @Persistent
    private String hour;

    public Message(String text, String hour)
    {
        this.text = text;
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public String getText() 
    {
        return text;
    }

    public String getHour() 
    {
        return hour;
    }

    public Key getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }

    public Conversation getConversation() {
        return conversation;
    }
}
```

Besides I have tried to get the messages separately and I successfully get them. The messages are saving well, but the list of them in conversation is missing.

I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I save the conversation after I add the messages with this code:

```
final PersistenceManager persistenceManager = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();      
final Conversation conversation = new Conversation(idUser1, idUser2);

//Add the messages successfully

try 
{
    persistenceManager.makePersistent(conversation);
} finally {
    persistenceManager.close();
}
```

And I get the conversation with that one:

```
final PersistenceManager persistenceManager = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();  
Long idConversation;

//Got the idConversation with a query successfully

Conversation conversation = persistenceManager.getObjectById(Conversation.class, idConversation);
return conversation;
```

Comment: Suggest you go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110506/jdo-basics-list-or-array-wont-persist and look at my reply there and answer the very same questions

Comment: I have read that post before, but I don`t know what it`s supossed to do with my problem. I must read the articles and that`s all?

Comment: The other thread : user has class with List, user says he persists, user has problem seeing the List on retrieval, user doesn't mention version of software being used, user doesn't quote from log which states what calls are made to the datastore. Those are the key aspects of your post. Start by answering those points ... the version used, the log entries, what is your retrieval code

Comment: Ok, I have been doing test and I have discovered some things. At first, I think that I have the version 3.1 of Datanucleus, but I am not sure. Besides, I have ckecked in the admin panel of my database that the messages are well saved, and the conversations have the relationship with these messages. However, when I get a conversation from the database, the list of messages is still null, instead of return the list that is in the database. I don`t understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state how you retrieve the object from the datastore, and where you access the List. Within a transaction? Outside a transaction ? what state is the object in ? hollow? detached? Is the List in the current fetch group when you retrieve the owning object?

Put the list in the current fetch group.

Comment: The Conversation will have a property for the List with the Keys of the message objects. That tells you if it is correctly persisted. Then look at the datanucleus log for the retrieve, and make sure you put the List of Conversation in the FetchPlan.

Comment: Sorry but I`m new in JDO, and I don`t know what is the FetchPlan. The Conversation have a property for the list with the Keys of the message object, and the database have the list of the keys too, so I don`t know what I`m doing wrong.

Comment: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/fetchgroup.html defines how to add fields to the "fetch group" (what is retrieved). For example pm.getFetchPlan().setGroup("all"); All of that is in the DN docs and JDO spec

Comment: Oh, I`m sorry for not reading that before but there isn`t in the Google App Engine documentation. However, what is supossed that I must do with my database? If all the data is being well-saved, why I cant get the data correctly?

Comment: GAE documentation says "See the Access Platform 3.0 documentation for more information about JDO". I already told you above how to retrieve the List field ... put it in the fetch plan. Es que la documentacion de Google es de ellos, y como has elegido usar JDO debes entender los fetch groups por que soluciona tu problema, y esta en la documentacion de DataNucleus o la especificacion de JDO.

Comment: Vaya, hablas español, que casualidad. Si fueras tan amable de indicarme algo de documentación para poder aprender los "Fetch Groups" te estaría eternamente agradecido (Si fuera en español mejor xD). La verdad es que GAE me parece práctico hasta cierto punto, pero por ahora quiero seguir con ello, y para eso necesito saber cómo coger la maldita lista de mensajes. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, de verdad. Un saludo.

Comment: Asi que ya has leido el enlace que puse arriba ? datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/fetchgroup.html por que explica todo relacionado con fetch groups, y incluso puse arriba "persistenceManager.getFetchPlan().setGroup("all");" que podria solucionarlo.

Comment: Oh, vaya, lo lamento mucho, no me había dado ni cuenta. La verdad es que le eché un vistazo al enlace que me dejaste pero no entiendo mucho de inglés, así que no pude sacar nada en claro. La idea es que vaya probando "@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup="true")" con "persistenceManager.getFetchPlan().setGroup("all");" y con PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
pm.getFetchPlan().addGroup("otherfield");" para ir dándole forma a los grupos dentro de mi base de datos, no? Te agradezco infinitamente la ayuda que me estás brindando, de verdad. Un saludo.

Comment: Vale, he probado diferentes combinaciones del Fetch Group y al final he sacado la forma de recuperar los mensajes. Te lo agradezco mucho, porque la verdad no me hubiera gustado dejar a estas alturas el GAE. Gracias de corazón. En otro orden de cosas, al ir avanzando me he dado cuenta de que si envío dos mensajes mas o menos al mismo tiempo uno de los dos se pierde. Asumo que es porque ambos acceden a la base de datos antigua y la guardan, sobreescribiendo el anterior mensaje. Sabes alguna manera de solucionarlo?? (Si no no te preocupes que abro otra pregunta). Muchas gracias por todo!!!

Comment: Si quieres ver la comunicacion con la base de datos tendrias que mirar al log http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/logging.html  y al nivel "DEBUG", que muestra cada "PUT" a la base de datos. Salvo eso, la base de datos y no JDO tiene responsabilidad de retener los objetos.

Comment: Si, entiendo que sea la base de datos y no JDO la que tiene que retener los objetos, pero bes si hay alguna forma de poner las llamadas en una cola o una especie de pila para ir sacando registros a guardar en la base de datos y que no se pierda ninguno? O sino alguna otra manera de hacerlo o algo? Es que si estoy intentando hacer un chat y si mi amigo y yo escribimos algo a la vez y uno de los mensajes se pierde no puede ser funcional...

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to instantiate the entity list member. The istantiation of lists done in a Jo's annotation tool with reflection as part of the jpa implementation.